# Change of variables method for surface integrals

Tags: differential-geometry, surface-integrals, change-of-variable

Let $\phi: \partial B_1(0) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function where $\partial B_1(0) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| = 1\}$ .

Defining:

$$S = \{\phi(x)x : x\in \partial B_1(0)\}$$

I am interested in calculating the 'surface' integral:

$$\int_S f(z)\,ds(z)$$

I wonder if there is a way to use the change of variable $z = \phi(x)x$ to transform this integral into a surface integral over $\partial B_1(0)$. I want something that resembles the following:

$$\int_S f(z)\,ds(z) = \int_{\partial B_1(0)} f(z(x)) \left|\frac{dz}{dx}\right| \,ds(x)$$

The problem is that I am not sure how to interpret the 'Jacobian' $\left|\frac{dz}{dx}\right|$ in this context.

Until now, I had tried to do it in the case of $n = 2$, and here is what I achieved.

Parameterizing with $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$, we have:

\begin{align}
x & = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta) \\
z & = (\phi\cos\theta, \phi\sin\theta)
\end{align}

This implies that:

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{d\theta} & = (-\sin\theta, \cos\theta) \\
\frac{dz}{d\theta} & = \left(\frac{d\phi}{d\theta}\cos\theta - \phi\sin\theta, \frac{d\phi}{d\theta}\sin\theta + \phi\cos\theta\right)
\end{align}

And after doing the calculations, it is not difficult to see that:

\begin{align}
\left\|\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right\| & = 1\\
\left\|\frac{dz}{d\theta}\right\| & = \sqrt{\left(\frac{d\phi}{d\theta}\right)^2 + \phi^2}
\end{align}

With this parameterization, we have that:

\begin{align}
\int_S f(z)\,ds(z) & = \int_0^{2\pi} f(\phi\cos\theta, \phi\sin\theta)\sqrt{\left(\frac{d\phi}{d\theta}\right)^2 + \phi^2} \, d\theta \\
& = \int_0^{2\pi} f(\phi\cos\theta, \phi\sin\theta)\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_1}\frac{dx_1}{d\theta} + \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_2}\frac{dx_2}{d\theta}\right)^2 + \phi^2} \, d\theta \\
& = \int_0^{2\pi} f(\phi(\cos\theta, \sin\theta))\sqrt{\left(-\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_1}\sin\theta + \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_2}\cos\theta\right)^2 + \phi^2} \, d\theta \\
& = \int_{\partial B_1(0)} f(\phi x) \sqrt{\left(-\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_1}x_2 + \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_2}x_1\right)^2 + \phi^2} \, ds(x)
\end{align}

I'm not 100% sure that my calculations have been correct. In any case, I would like to be able to interpret the term $\sqrt{\left(-\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_1}x_2 + \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_2}x_1\right)^2 + \phi^2}$ so that I can generalize it to higher dimensions.

Comment: Well, what is the derivative of the mapping $\Phi(x)=\phi(x)x$? Pretend, perhaps, that you’ve smoothly extended $\phi$ to a neighborhood of the sphere. Working with differential forms may be advisable.

Comment: I believe that $D\Phi(x) = x \nabla\phi(x)^T + \phi(x)I_{n \times n}$. However, I am not sure if $\int_S f(z) \, ds(z) = \int_{\partial B_1(0)} f(z(x)) \left|x \nabla\phi(x)^T + \phi(x)I_{n \times n}\right| \, ds(x)$.

Comment: No, because you need a Jacobian for a mapping from $S^{n-1}$ to its $(n-1)$-dimensional image. Why don't you work this out explicitly for $n=2$ and $n=3$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, I edited the post by adding the case for $n = 2$, but I still can't fully grasp how the change of variable would look like in higher dimensions.

Comment: Actually, here $\phi$ is a function of $\theta$, as it’s a function on the circle. So the first line is it. Try $n=3$ next. Remember that $\phi$ is a function on the sphere. You want $\sqrt{\det((D\Phi)^\top(D\Phi))}$, ultimately.

Comment: So, have I done it correctly in the case where $n = 2$? Also, I have a question, isn't it true that $\sqrt{\det((D\Phi)^\top(D\Phi))} = \sqrt{\det((D\Phi)^\top)\det((D\Phi))} = \sqrt{\det(D\Phi)\det(D\Phi)} = \sqrt{\det(D\Phi)^2} = |\det(D\Phi)|$

Comment: I already commented on the $n=2$ case. Stop at the first line. No, $D\Phi$ is not a square matrix.